# How do I change the chapter capitalization?

Tags: numbering, lyx, chapters, sections-paragraphs

I'm using LyX version 2.1.5

For example true ...

> CHAPTER I
>   INTRODUCTION
>
> 1.1 A title
>
> lorem epsum lorem epsum lorem epsum lorem epsum lorem epsum lorem epsum

---

LaTeX Preamble:

```
\renewcommand\MakeUppercase{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{introduction}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\section{A title}

lorem epsum lorem epsum lorem epsum lorem epsum lorem epsum lorem epsum
```

This output false ...

> Chapter I
>   INTRODUCTION
>
> 1.1 A title
>
> lorem epsum lorem epsum lorem epsum lorem epsum lorem epsum lorem
>   epsum

---

I still want change chapter capitalization but can't change, I do not know where the mistakes of others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the `\thesection` counter representation to include your chapter numbering. Typically this is done using

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
```

This would ensure consistency between the numbering of the chapter and how that is contained with the section numbering, since the definition is somewhat recursive.

If you want the `\section`al units to be numbered in Arabic even though `\chapter`s are numbered in Roman numerals, then you can use

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I still want to improve chapter into capital, I do not know to change

Comment: @Rahmat: For changing `Chapter` into `CHAPTER`, you could add `\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{\MakeUppercase{Chapter}}
\makeatother` to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble.